# How to swap one large tmux pane with several smaller ones?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, tmux

How do you swap one large tmux pane with several smaller ones?
In other word: from an arrangement like **A** – to an arrangement like **B**:

```
                  A                     ┊                     B
      ┏───────────────────────┓         ┊         ┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
      │                       │         ┊         │       │       │       │ 
      │           1           │         ┊         │   2   │   3   │   4   │
      │                       │         ┊         │       │       │       │
      ┡───────┬───────┬───────┩         ┊         ┢───────┴───────┴───────┪
      │       │       │       │         ┊         │                       │ 
      │   2   │   3   │   4   │         ┊         │           1           │ 
      │       │       │       │         ┊         │                       │ 
      └───────┴───────┴───────┘         ┊         ┗───────────────────────┛
```

There are plenty of resources covering similar operations, but not quite this.

- <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> / <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> moves the focus to another pane.
- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> / <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> adjusts their dimensions.
- <kbd>Space</kbd> cycles various pane layouts / arrangements.
- <kbd>{</kbd> / <kbd>}</kbd> shoves individual panes left / right – but that just forces a direct swap, like:

```
                  A                     ┊                     C
      ┏───────────────────────┓         ┊         ┌───────────────────────┐
      │                       │         ┊         │                       │ 
      │           1           │         ┊         │           2           │
      │                       │         ┊         │                       │
      ┡───────┬───────┬───────┩         ┊         ┢───────┱───────┬───────┤
      │       │       │       │         ┊         │       │       │       │ 
      │   2   │   3   │   4   │         ┊         │   1   │   3   │   4   │ 
      │       │       │       │         ┊         │       │       │       │ 
      └───────┴───────┴───────┘         ┊         ┗───────┹───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Note, if you are doing this a lot for 2 fixed layouts, once you have the 2 layouts you can save them to a file and toggle between them. See similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56343223/5008284).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-f` option of `tmux split-window`. The new pane will span the full window height (with `-h`) or full window width (with `-v`).

1. Create a new pane at the very bottom:

   ```
   tmux split-window -vf
   ```
2. Invoke `tmux display-panes` (or <kbd>prefix</kbd>,<kbd>q</kbd>) to identify the two panes you want to swap: the top one and the bottom one.
3. Let's say these panes are `0` and `3`. Swap them:

   ```
   tmux swap-pane -s 0 -t 3
   ```

   Or you can mark one pane (RMB) and run just `tmux swap-pane` in the other.
4. Destroy the top pane.

---

Or run this in the top pane:

```
tmux split-window -vf "tmux swap-pane -dt '$TMUX_PANE'"
```

To "undo" (i.e. "move" large bottom pane to top) run this in the bottom pane:

```
tmux split-window -vfb "tmux swap-pane -dt '$TMUX_PANE'"
```

---

Or mark the top pane (RMB), open the tmux command prompt (<kbd>prefix</kbd>,<kbd>:</kbd>) and execute this:

```
split-window -vf "tmux swap-pane -d"
```

This is useful when your top pane is busy and you cannot execute commands in a shell there.